# imagemagick montage - how to align images to bottom

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-montage

I want to create a montage, using ImageMagick, where all the images are aligned to the bottom. The images have different heights, and `-gravity South` doesn't behave as I expect.

- Image 1 is 100px high.
- Image 2 is 200px high.

If I use :

```
montage *.png -tile 2x1 -background None -geometry +20+0 -gravity South out/montage.png
```

I get:

[image]

If I add a third image, of 50px high, and run

```
montage *.png -tile 3x1 -geometry +20+0 -gravity South montage2.jpg
```

I get:

[image]

I understand what's happening here - the canvas is expanding from the bottom. Is there any way to get it to grow from the top, so that the image looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

You can just use +smush ([documentation](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#smush)) for that:

```
convert -background white -gravity south [abc].png +smush 10 result.png
```

If using Imagemagick v7, replace `convert` with `magick`.